# Запятые: можно ли их опускать, если они выглядят чересчур нарочито?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация

Я довольно много пишу на английском, и там запятые используются гораздо реже. Я к этому привык, но главное — я считаю, что так действительно лучше.

Ну вот, к примеру, заголовок моего вопроса:

> Запятые: можно ли их опускать[,] если они выглядят чересчур нарочито?

Я не особо знаток пунктуации, но думаю, что по правилам запятая там нужна. Но выглядит она топорно, словно бы я обращаюсь к туповатому собеседнику.

Или вот ещё примеры:

> - Простые массивы — используй[,] когда ты не нуждаешься в парадигме "ключ - значение".
> - Ассоциативные — используй[,] когда потребность в такой парадигме есть.

Проверил по Гуглу, запятые вроде нужны, но режут глаз, точнее "слух".

Кто виноват и что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, пунктуация в английском и русском отличается. Но ведь в разных языках свои "законы". На каком основании можно опускать запятые там, где они нужны по правилам? Авторская пунктуация (Вы поставили эту метку) не может быть произвольной, не считающейся с основными принятыми нормами письма.

И ещё: интонация далеко не всегда может подсказать, где ставить знаки препинания; мы часто в речи делаем паузу в длинном предложении, но не ставим запятые в этих местах без необходимости, и наоборот (хотя и реже, поскольку наличие запятой всё же не случайно и, соответственно, определяет паузу).

В Ваших предложениях запятые не выглядят нарочито (это, скорее, субъективно), они должны там быть и даже интонационно разделяют фразы.